# how to replace calculator symbols when it is zero

Tags: javascript, html, css

have a problem with my calculator..want to add numbers if my start value is 0 and it is not '-+/*'..what is my problem?

```
    function addToZero (value)
    {   
        var symbols = /[0-9/]/;

        if (symbols.test(calculator.answer.value) && (parseInt(calculator.answer.value) === 0))
        {   
            calculator.answer.value=+calculator.answer.value; 
        }
        else 
            alert("Ничего не делать");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
calculator.answer.value=+calculator.answer.value;
```

this is not correct syntax.

```
calculator.answer.value += calculator.answer.value;
```

This will put value to the end.
But normally you put first the value in a variabele and after ward you put it on the end.

```
var calcVal = calculator.answer.value;

calcVal  += calculator.answer.value;
```